# Search for a specify string in a specified position on a sentence

Tags: python, python-3.x, string, if-statement, boolean

I am trying to search for a given string in a specified location in the sentence. A name is embedded in a sentence and I want to search if that said name is present or not.

The sentence is:
s = Category: Image_by_Thoma_for_my_favourite_Theme

My python code is:

```
If 'Th' in s:
    print('present')
```

Note that this will return present because of 'Thoma' and 'Theme'.
So I guess the best approach is using a regex to get the exact position of 'Thoma' and return present. I am new to python and I really do not know much about regex orr Is there a way to check if the word 'Thoma' is positioned exactly after the words in s?

Comment: See string slicing. You can get a part of a string. So you can check if the part your looking for is equal to what you are looking for. `if s[pos:pos+len(SOMETHING)]== SOMETHING` where the `pos` is the start position and `SOMETHING` is the thing you are looking for

Comment: @MSH thanks but what about the underscore(_)? I was thing regex would be the best approach

Comment: Python's `str` has an `index` method. You can get the first index of a value. In your example, you can get the position of the word `Thomas` by `s.index('Thomas')`. Regex is a good approach but as I know for this kind of example regex is slow. Just be careful the `index` returns the first available position. This means if you have multiple `Thomas`s you'll get the position of the first one.

Answer (score 0):

I hope I've understood your question correctly. Are you searching for word that is after `Image_by_`? You can use Regex for that:

```py
import re

s = "Category: Image_by_Thoma_for_my_favourite_Theme"

pat = re.compile(r"Image_by_([^_]+)")

match = pat.search(s)
if match:
    print(match.group(1))
```

Prints:

```
Thoma
```

---

You can then check, if the `.group(1)` is equal to `Thoma`, or use `str.startswith` to check if the name starts with `Th`.